# More advanced mathematic typesetting using groff and eqn?

Tags: linux, math, equation, groff

I've been learning Groff and eqn for document typesetting - I'm a physics and mathematics student, so a lot of my documents require semi-complex mathematical formatting.
Generally, I'm using eqn for the equations, and it's working well, but I've found a distinct lack of documentation over certain features.

For instance, the approximately equals sign, set theory symbols, - over + instead of + over -, etc... I can't seem to find a way to type them.

Is there a list of all of the symbols eqn has/supports and their syntax? If not, where should I start in making this list myself?

It just feels odd that a piece of software over 40 years old now hasn't got this kinda st uff available in large online tables, the way LaTeX does. If anyone has any information, I'd be really grateful.

Thanks

Comment: This is a great question, but I'm not sure where best to ask about it. Maybe superuser.com?

Comment: Ah, apologies for misplacing the question. I will post it over at superuser.